# sudo doesn't request a password after installing PiNet

Tags: command-line, password, sudo

After installing [PiNet](http://pinet.org.uk/) on my Ubuntu machine, I noticed that `sudo` is no longer prompting me for a password. This is still the case after rebooting or after running `sudo -k`:

```
$ whoami 
thang 
$ sudo whoami 
root 
$ sudo -k 
$ sudo whoami 
root
```

As you can see above, no password prompt was printed. The `thang` user is not UID 1:

```
$ grep thang /etc/passwd 
thang:x:1000:1000:thang,,,:/home/thang:/bin/bash
```

And there doesn't seem to be anything strange in my `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

There is also a file called `01staff` in `/etc/sudoers.d`:

```
$ cat /etc/sudoers.d/01staff
%teacher ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

In case it's relevant, the groups that `thang` belongs to are:

```
$ groups thang 
thang : thang adm dialout cdrom sudo audio dip video plugdev games users input lpadmin sambashare pupil teacher
```

Running GUI programs that require root access still prompts me for a password but terminal commands do not. What is going on here?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `sudo cat /etc/sudoers` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I added it. I think that nothing's wrong with it.

Comment: There is a timeout. You do not need to enter the password again if you entered it once. If you close the terminal and start it again, does it ask for a password?

Comment: I restarted my computer, but it still occured. Can I fix it with a live USB.

Comment: What user are you logging in as? Sounds like you're logged in as "root".

Comment: @terdon But I restarted my computer. I opened another terminal. Nothing happened. :(( How can I check if I'm logging as "root" each time my computer turn on?

Comment: You probably enter a username when you log in. If not, open a terminal and run `whoami`. That will tell you your user name. Also, please clarify what you're doing, where do you have a GUI and where do you not have one?

Comment: @terdon I checked it and I'm not the "root" user. When I use GUI applications like Gparted or ImageWriter, an authenticate window appears and I can type password. But in terminal I don't need to password.

Comment: This is very hard to understand I'm afraid. Please join me [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29726/room-for-terdon-and-ngoc-thang-pham) to discuss it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, installing PiNet created the `teachers` group, added your user to it and also created the file in `/etc/sudoers.d`. This line:

```
%teacher ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Gives the right to all members of the `teachers` group to run `sudo` commands without providing a password. So, simply delete it and you should be fine:

```
sudo rm /etc/sudoers.d/01staff
```

PiNet seems to be a program to facilitate administrating a classroom full fo Pis and, apparently, believes that all teachers should have passwordless sudo rights.

If you do actually want to keep that setup, just remove your user from the `teachers` group:

```
sudo usermod -G  adm dialout cdrom sudo audio dip video plugdev games users input lpadmin sambashare pupil
```